# Check to see if DataView is Empty

Tags: c#, dataview

I'm trying to determine if a `DataView` does not contain data.

```
 lsSql = "Select col1, col2 from table where tableId = " + Id;
 DataView loCheck = Global.db.GetDataView(lsSql);
 if (loCheck .Count > 0)
 {
     checkSelected= true;
 } else {
     checkSelected= false;
 }
```

Currently if col1 and col2 are empty I get 2 rows (null) returned and checkSelected is always equal to true.

How can I see if a DataView doesn't contain any data?

Comment: Are you wanting false if both `col1` AND `col2` are null? or only if one is null, not the other?

Comment: I want true if 1 is set.  So false if both are set.

Comment: I think i may have misread your last comment.  If you mean "true if one is set [to null], so false if both are set [to null]"  Then my answer should have it.  If i've misunderstood, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
if (loCheck.Table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
      checkSelected= true;
}
else
{
      checkSelected= false;
}
```

Comment: The OP has said that he gets two rows even when the values are null.  How is this any different?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a single value based on the results of two columns being null or not, [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or nullif is your sql method. ([NullIf](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) is the same thing, but only takes two parameters, whereas I suggest 3)

```
"Select coalesce(col1, col2, 'false') as result from table where tableId = " + Id
```

Then testing your value is trivial:

```
if(loCheck.Rows[0]["result"].ToString() == "false")
   checkSelected= false;
else
   checkSelected= true;
```

Comment: I'd be careful of using string concatenation in your sql.  Parameters are better to avoid sql injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the length based on a "Select" of the result looking for null in both columns, but you need to determine the condition.  Do you care about the row if EITHER 1 HAS a value in either column, or do you consider it ignored if either column is null... OR, do you consider it missing data ONLY WHEN BOTH columns are null...

```
chkSelected = loCheck.Table.Select( "Col1 is NOT null AND Col2 is NOT null" ).Length > 0;
```

Then you can set the filter of your default view to this clause to skip the NULL entries.

This could ALSO be applied directly with the original query by explicitly EXCLUDING the NULL records so you are not bothered with them by just adding a to the WHERE clause

```
where tableId = someKey AND ( Col1 is not null AND Col2 is not null )
```

or

```
where tableId = someKey AND ( Col1 is not null OR Col2 is not null )
```